# Self-describing matchstick number

Tags: matches

The word "SIX" can be spelled with six matchsticks (if you'll forgive my "S").

[image]

What is the next whole number *n* that can be spelled (in English, in all capital letters) with exactly *n* matchsticks?

You shall not break a match in two, nor redundantly double up matches on the same edge of a letter.  You may, however, take advantage of glyph variants like one-stick sans-serif "I" versus three-stick seriffed "I".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with

> 10, if you are willing to have a really big capital E (which looks kind of funny, but I'll argue that it's a reasonable way to write the E)

with

> Standard 2 sticks for T and 3 for N, but build the E as a backwards 3 from a digital clock, which uses 5 sticks.

Comment: Unorthodox, but I'll count it.

Comment: @dan04 shouldn't this be the correct answer?

Answer (score 6):

You can do

> 29

So, it would look like

> [image]

Comment: I can visualize this